# SQL: LEFT JOIN for each value

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm a begginer with SQL and got a small problem. Let's assume I got a table looking like:

```
 ID Month
 1   Jan
 2   Feb
 2   June
 3   Dec
```

Now I want to have that every ID-Value got every month, ie

```
ID Month
1  Jan
1  Feb
.  .
.
.
2 Jan
2 Feb
.
.
and so on.
```

I tried to create another table including all months and the use of the command "Left Join". But this only includes all months once for the whole table, but not for every ID seperately.

I tried:

```
 Create Table merged as 
   select ID, Month 
   from Data 
   Left outer join months On data.month=months.month;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: And show us your query attempt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if that's a dumb question, but what do you mean with that question?

Comment: I tried: 
Create Table merged as select ID, Month
from Data
Left outer join months
On data.month=months.month;

Comment: @Michael: jarlh hasn't asked a question, he just wanted that you show your attempt. A question on SO must always contain an attempt and an issue. Then we can help to fix this issue. SO is a problem- not a requirement solving site ;)

Comment: So what is the DBMS you are using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I'm using SAS, if that is answering the question/comment :-)

Comment: What is SAS? Where's your query?

Answer (score 2):

You would typically do this with a `cross join`.  If all months are in the table, then you can do:

```
select i.id, m.month
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct month from t) m;
```

You may have another source for the lists of `id`s and `month`s.

EDIT:

Michael, normally when you are asking a *new* question, you should do it as another question.  This question clearly does not have an `outcome` column; changing the question would invalidate this answer and hence draw downvotes -- so that is rude.

But, this is an easy change to the query:

```
select i.id, m.month, t.outcome
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct month from t) m left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.month = m.month;
```

Comment: Or how would I do that with an additional table with all months?

Comment: I was able to use your code, but got one problem: in my table I got a third column (saying outcome). How can I include that in the new table? By writing select id, month, outcome.... i got an error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ID,A._Month FROM #Table T1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT ID,_Month FROM #Table) A ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.